# Exclude certain row as default if a column value is zero in eloquent like soft delete LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I do not know if it's possible. The problem is I have a Model that has already been in use for long time and has been used many times in code. Now what I want to do is add a one column that defines if the certain row should be passed as regular call or not like soft delete where if the model has delete_at column, the row wont be passed as default model call. I do not want to go through each model call and add a scope or where clause because there is many of it.

So, How can I add feature like soft delete for a Model to ignore certain row with conditioned column in a default call?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to add a scope/conditions on each call, you can use Global Scopes. It will always be added in your Model's queries.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: In fact, soft deletion is implemented through global scopes.